# PDF Form Generation

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application that needs to create application forms for insurance. Basically, the program loads a PDF Template, populates the form fields, then flattens and closes the PDF. The templates are small when I create them from Word (about 156k for 5 pages) but each form field added to the template via Adobe Acrobat adds about 5-10k to the overall file size. Unfortunately, these pages have a whole lot of form fields (200+), and the end result tends to be about half a MB to a 1 MB per page.

Can anyone suggest an alternate application, usable dynamically from an ASP.NET webpage, that can do a similar job but maintain a smaller file size? It doesn't need to be a free component, but it does need to have a way for me to create a template from a word document but not use Office automation to populate the word doc and save as PDF. My preference would also be that it deal with streams and not files, but that is a minor consideration for me in the circumstances.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe's Save As... Reduced Size PDF?  I've seen it knock 100KB or so off of a single form page with 80 or so form fields on it when forcing compatibility to Acrobat 9 or 10.

Comment: @ChrisLively, yes I have tried that option. Unfortunately, the appears to be some upper limit after which Adobe goes haywire because when I tried that more than half the form fields would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm), I'm pretty sure it can handle what you're looking for

Comment: I didnt think abcpdf had any built in templating stuff, would probably need to be done as a manual step before hand

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for this.

The library can be used to fill existing fields from code or by importing FDF files.

The library can not flatten form fields but you can make fields read-only or protect the whole document from changes with permissions.

Here are some sample that might be useful:

- [Fill existing form](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FillForm)
- [Import FDF data](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/ImportFdfData)
- [Find control by name](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FindControlByName)
- [Permissions](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Security/Permissions)

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com).  You can use word documents as templates to populate and produce PDF and other outputs.  Because of the way it works, the document size will not "explode" as you have indicated is a problem with a large number of fields with your current scenario.  ASP.NET can invoke Docmosis in various ways depending on your application's runtime environment.  Docmosis offers online web-services which have minimal footprint/requirements for an application environment as well as downloadable and embeddable options.  It is commercial (I work for the company that created it) and has no Office Automation requirements.

Hope that helps.